# Embed "Bokeh created html file" into Flask "template.html" file

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, bokeh

I have a web application written in Python - Flask. When the user fill out some settings in one of the pages (POST Request), my controller calculates some functions and plot an output using Bokeh with following command and then I redirect to that HTML page created by Bokeh.

```
output_file("templates\\" + idx[j]['name'] + ".html", title = "line plots")
TOOLS="resize,crosshair,pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,box_select,lasso_select"
p = figure(tools=TOOLS, x_axis_label = 'time', y_axis_label = 'L', plot_width = 1400, plot_height = 900)
```

All of my HTML pages extends my "Template.HTML" file except the Bokeh generated ones. My question is how can automatically modify Bokeh generated HTML files to also extends my template.html file?  This way I have all my nav-bar & jumbotron on top of the Bokeh html files.

```
  {% extends "template.html" %}
  {% block content %}

  <Bokeh.html file>

  {% endblock %}
```

Comment: Created a test.html file with content of: {% extends "template.html" %}{% block content %}{{ script }}{{ div }} {% endblock %}. Also in my controller: added return render_template('test.html', script = script, div = div), where script and div = components(p). Also, added the proper <link stylesheet> and <script javascript> for Bokeh to my template.html file. Unfortunately, it does not work fine. Based on Guide, the <Script> should go to my <head> part of template. However, my setup force it to go to the <body> part between{% block content %}{% endblock %}.

Comment: Please don't put relevant information in a *comment*. You can use [edit] to add it to your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't want to use `output_file` in this situation.  Bokeh has a function specifically for embedding into HTML templates in web apps, `bokeh.embed.component`, demonstrated in the [quickstart](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#components) and [tutorial](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/bokeh/bokeh-notebooks/blob/master/tutorial/05%20-%20sharing.ipynb).

```
from bokeh.embed import components
script, div = components(plot)
return render_template('page.html', script=script, div=div)
```

```html
<body>
{{ div|safe }}
{{ script|safe }}
</body>
```

[Here is a complete, runnable example that that shows how to use this with Flask.](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/master/examples/embed/simple)

Comment: This post spawned a [discussion on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309037/is-there-anything-that-can-be-done-to-educate-established-users-about-how-to-con)